# How to split each character on a String from user input?

Tags: java, string, split

I found many questions already answer like this one, I, however, either didn't comprehend the answers or they were no what i needed. I appreciate any help. Thank you.

I need to take a string entered by a user and separate the characters with in that string. To clarify I will give the next example: if the user enters a1, b1, or c1 (which are the only choices) I need to take the string entered (lets say a1) and separate a from 1. This is so that i can use them individually at a later time.

Comment: Have you tried `string.split(",")`?

Comment: Do you enforce the choice of input?

Comment: If the only choices are a1/b1/c1, why not store 1 in a variable and ask the user for a/b/c?

Comment: @AlexandruSeverin i explained my self wrong the choices are a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6 and they all will form part of an array at a certain point sho show a row and associated column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
String str = "a1";
char[] splitted = str.toCharArray();
char letter = splitted[0];
char number = splitted[1];
```

Now you have them both in a separate variable:

```
System.out.println(letter);  // prints a
System.out.println(number);  // prints 1
```

---

If your inputs get more complicated like ab123 and you want ab and 123 separated, you can do this:

```
String str = "ab123";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)").matcher(str);
m.find();
String letters = m.group(1);
String numbers = m.group(2);
```

Comment: okay this is perfect. how can i than convert a the char number to an int?

Comment: Yes, simply do: `int valueOfNumber = number - '0';`. Or if you have a String, use: `int valueOfNumber = Integer.parseInt(numbers);`.

Comment: so basically I am just creating a separate variable holding the char as an int?

Answer (score 0):

```
string.split("");//returns string[] array of characters
```

or you may use

```
string.toCharArray();//char array is returned
```

If you don't want to use latte; you can compare like this

```
if (string.equals("a1"))
   //you code
```